# using Excel functions to count unique values in one column based on match in other column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel question - is there a method of using functions to count all of the unique values of a column based on matching another column's contents with a particular data interest? For example, suppose I have two columns of data.

```
A           | B
toothbrush  | AAA
shampoo     | AAA
toothbrush  | AAA
toothbrush  | BBB
conditioner | CCC
toothbrush  | BBB
shampoo     | CCC
toothbrush  | CCC
toothpaste  | CCC
toothpaste  | AAA
toothbrush  | AAA
shampoo     | BBB
```

I would like to generate, on a separate tab, two columns that display the following information, for example:

```
C           | D
toothbrush  | 3
toothpaste  | 2
shampoo     | 3
conditioner | 1
```

Column D would be the number of unique customers for each of the 4 products.

Is there a way to do this in Column D using a formula composed of SUM, IF, COUNTIF, etc.?

Thanks in advance and please let me know if I can clarify anything further.

Comment: I had the incorrect value, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Is there any way to do it without using a PivotTable though, but with Functions?

Comment: That solution is not what I'm seeking to do.

Comment: What function are you talking about then? When you say function, I assume excel built in formulas?

Comment: I apologize - I meant to say Excel's built-in formulas, yeah!

Comment: So the link I posted do just that. From a list of items, the formula (array formula) returns all unique items in a column. After you get the unique items, you can use a regular *COUNTIF* function. Isn't that what you want done? Or maybe I misunderstood your question?

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to use Formula's that would have each product string, for example "toothbrush", as a condition where it would scan all of the lines in the original data, look for "toothbrush" occurrences, and then evaluate how many unique customers there are for "toothbrushs"...and so on for the other products. Hopefully this helps clear confusion?

Comment: Too bad you don't want using PT because that is certainly the easiest. But let me check if there's a way to get that you want... I'll get back as soon as I can.

Comment: Ok, the best approach would be to use a Pivot Table. If you're using 2013, @pnuts posted the answer:). If not, you can [try this](http://www.pivot-table.com/2010/03/22/count-unique-items-in-an-excel-pivot-table/)

Answer (score 1):

Since others may not be so particular about what readily available tools they decide to avoid, create a PivotTable with "Add this data to the Data Model" with A for ROWS and B for VALUES, then change Count of B to Distinct Count of B.

[image: SO25755209 example]

Comment: This is available only for 2013. :)

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't matter as well since OP seems not interested on using PT in one of the comments.

Answer (score 0):

For the list of unique items, this will do the trick (it will produce blank cells as well):

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A$1:A1,Sheet1!A1)>1,"",Sheet1!A1)
```

Put `=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet1!$B$1:B1,Sheet1!B1)>1,"",Sheet1!B1)` into column E to produce unique customers.

Finally, put this into column D, making sure to extend it to accommodate the number of rows on sheet1 and pressing `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` to make it an array formula:

```
{=IF(A1="","",
SUM(IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$12,A1,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$12,$C$1:$C$12)>0,1,0)))}
```